# ERROR: raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

*I code this to download some websites. But it can't run without error*

The pages can be downloaded, but instead of printing "download finished", it print error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Copy\Desktop\gethanhan.py", line 28, in <module>
    con = urllib.urlopen(my_url[j]).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 463, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 477, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] : ''
```

I test it for hours. But I still cannot find the problem. Here is the code:

```
......
#use a list which have urls to download url pages
j = 0
while j<50:
    con = urllib.urlopen(my_url[j]).read()
    filename = my_url[j][-26:]
    print 'Downloading'
    full_path ='F:/Copy/Desktop/kankan/' + str(j) + '.html'

    #ERROR appears in here:
    open(full_path,'w+').write(con) 
    j += 1
else:
    print 'Download finished'
```

Comment: Do you *have* a directory `F:/Copy/Desktop/kankan`?

Comment: No, but I set open() to "w+".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the directory `F:/Copy/Desktop/kankan` for this to work.

Opening a file with `w+` does *not* create directories for you. It only signals that you want to open a file for both reading and writing and that it should be cleared (truncated) first.

Use the [`os.makedirs()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) if you also need to create parent directories.

For your `while` loop, I'd leave off the `else:` altogether. Just dedent the `print 'Download finished'` line instead.

Your second error is for a URL being opened as a *local file*. Check the URL, it points to a file on your harddisk that does not exist.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!But I have set open() to "w+". Won't it create kankan automatically?

Comment: It works, however it doesn't print "download finished" after finish the loop. And it prints another error. I've sent the second error to the question body.

Comment: You mean the second error ocurred by opening a path doesn't exits? Is there any solution for the second error? Because I can't create a file before I know what a file it is.

Comment: @user2741941: That depends on the URL you are trying to open; it *probably* means you tried to open a URL that is malformed.

Comment: What is the URL that throws that exception? Take a look at that to start with.

Answer (score 0):

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
```

I think the connection was forcibly closed by the remote host[kankan.com].
you can catch all exceptions as so:

```
try:
    open(full_path,'w+').write(con) 
except URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
except:
    print("Unknown Error")
```

Comment: KanKan is not a website. It's a folder name.